# How to find script running psql query?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to find a name of the script that runs psql query. From pg_stat_activity I can extract active query and pid, but this pid is of postgres process. If there any way to match that pid to pid of script (from ps for example)?

Comment: That's not possible. The server only sees individual SQL statements it has no idea about "scripts" on the client

Comment: If you run the script with `psql -f ....` then the pid of the psql process will generally be one less than the pid of the backend process.  There is no guarantee of this, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to make this work is to start every script with

```
SET application_name = 'psql executing myscript.sql';
```

and to end it with

```
SET application_name = 'psql';
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't find yet how to get the psql script name, that appears on error or on RAISE.

e.g. :
psql:/path/to/my_script.psql:9999: WARNING: error message.

I want to get the '/path/to/my_script.psql', to show in log what script is running. But failed to find the way to get it.

The workaround I use is to put at the top of my psql scripts this lines :

```
\set scr_nam 'my_script_name.psql === '

\set QUIET on \pset tuples_only on \pset format unaligned \pset pager \set QUIET
SELECT TO_CHAR(clock_timestamp(),'Dy DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,MS') || ' # ' || :'scr_nam' || 'START ===' msg;

<code>
the code of my psql script
</code>

\set QUIET on \pset format unaligned \pset tuples_only on \set QUIET off
SELECT TO_CHAR(clock_timestamp(),'Dy DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,MS') || ' # ' || :'scr_nam' || 'E N D ===' msg;
```